# Radial fan with both input and output on the same plane

Tags: airflow, fan

An axial fan moves air from one side to the other, where the fan is placed on the plane normal to the axis:

[image]

A radial fan, moves air from a normal axis to the same plane where the fan runs:

[image]

Is there a fan that moves air in the same plane as it rotates? Something like this:

[image]

Of course this is just an example. I'm not sure if this is possible and what is its name.

Comment: They are called cycloidal rotor fans.

Comment: Crossflow fans are a bit different in terms of form factor - long an small diameter, like those used in minisplit airhandlers.

Comment: @PhilSweet like this? https://www.researchgate.net/figure/SCHEMATIC-OF-A-CYCLOIDAL-ROTOR_fig1_342888421 I'm looking for something flat, like my last picture

Comment: @PhilSweet interesting, but is there something flat?